# This question has been said to off topic SU

Tags: support, javascript

I have a question about my Super User post: [Saving website leads to incomplete save](https://superuser.com/questions/1225784/saving-website-leads-to-incomplete-save)

I dont see this is off topic on SU, or I cannot see the real difference between meta and not meta... but I really want to know whats going on with these sites can anyone answer me please?